# Where can I get a list of days & months as CSV?

Tags: html

I am creating a reservation form for a website, they want a drop down for the dates not a calendar, I'm going to just use gravity forms.

I need a list of Days and months, e.g.

```
Sunday 1st May
Monday 2nd May
Tuesday 3rd May
```

I'm in the UK if that makes a difference :)

Thanks

Ricky

Comment: Yeah I'm Aware of that ;) All I'll need to do is move the days up one for each year so if the 1st is on a sunday today next year it'll be on a Saturday... Right?

Comment: For those who are confused like I was: [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/)

Comment: @RickyDawn: it's _not_ that easy. every now and then we have leap-years  where your "just move one up" doesn't work (you'll have to move 2 instead ;) ): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could easily create such a list on your own - for example using [php](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php):

- http://codepad.org/agsuUAKD

just change the `$start` and `$end` in the script-section. note that you'll have to constantly replace your csv-file to have current dates available without having a too long list - so this really sounds like a bad idea. instead, you should solve this in code (wich isn't that hard a s you can see) and automatically fill the dropdown with options.